# Cannot convert value of type 'SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, Data?>' to expected argument type

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I want to solve this error.
"Cannot convert value of type 'SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, ControlProperty<String?>.Element>' (aka 'SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, Optional>') to expected argument type 'Driver' (aka 'SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, String>')"
And
"Cannot convert value of type 'SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, Data?>' to expected argument type 'Driver' (aka 'SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, String>')"

But I don't know how to fix this error. I don't think something fits with the viewModel, but I don't know what it is. The place where the error occurs is the asDriver.
I am using RxSwift and MVVM patterns.

```
   func bindViewModel() {
        
        let api = ProfileAPI()
        let input = ModifyProfileViewModel.input(nickName: nickNameTxtField.rx.text.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: nil), userImage: image.asDriver(), doneTap: saveBtn.rx.tap.asSignal())
        let output = viewModel.transform(input)
        
        output.result.emit(onCompleted: { self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)}
        ).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
    }
```

This is my ViewController code

```
class ModifyProfileViewModel: ViewModelType {
    
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    
    struct input {
        let nickName: Driver<String>
        let userImage: Driver<String>
        let doneTap: Signal<Void>
    }
    
    struct output {
        let result: Signal<String>
        let isEnabled: Driver<Bool>
    }
    
    func transform(_ input: input) -> output {
        let api = ProfileAPI()
        let result = PublishSubject<String>()
        let info = Driver.combineLatest(input.nickName, input.userImage)
        let isEnabled = info.map { !$0.0.isEmpty }
        
        input.doneTap.withLatestFrom(info).asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { nickName, image in
            api.putModifyProfile().subscribe(onNext: { (response, statusCode) in
                switch statusCode {
                case .success:
                    result.onCompleted()
                case .noHere:
                    result.onNext("fail")
                default:
                    result.onNext("default")
                }
            }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        return output(result: result.asSignal(onErrorJustReturn: ""), isEnabled: isEnabled.asDriver())
        
    }
}
```

And this is my ViewModel code
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here: `nickNameTxtField.rx.text.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: nil)` is of type `Driver<String?>` but you are trying to assign it to a `Driver<String>`.

Either `map` the former with `.map { $0 ?? "" }` or change the latter to accept Optionals.